# vim - Keep getting E17 error

Tags: bash, vim

I am currently taking some online tutorials on VIM text editor through https://www.learnenough.com/text-editor-tutorial. One of the instruction is requiring me to create an alias for the bash profile as shown

```
~/.bash_profile
alias lr = 'ls -hartl'
```

and then save it using command as shown

```
:w
```

However, every time i tried to save, i get an error message

```
E17: "/users/myName" is a directory
```

Any help to fix this will be greatly appreciated
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put at least excerpt of the link if not the complete matter. Not everyone prefer to visit external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding their formatting in the tutorial.  You should interpret the following (line numbers added by me):

```
1. Listing 4: Defining a Bash alias.
2. ~/.bash_profile
3. alias lr='ls -hartl'
```

As:

1. Reference number and description of the listing.
2. Filename
3. Contents of filename

What you've done is opened vim and inserted both 2 and 3 into the buffer in reality you should open `~/.bash_profile` in vim and insert `alias lr='ls -hartl'` into that file.

You can open `~/.bash_profile` by running `vim ~/.bash_profile` at the command line or by running `:edit ~/.bash_profile` once vim is running.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces around the equal sign (that's the correct shell syntax):

```
alias lr='ls -hartl'
```